# Remove 0, if return 0 year or 0 month DateFormat

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, datetime-format, php-carbon

```
$createdTime = Carbon::parse($specialist->created_at)
                        ->diff(Carbon::now())
                        ->format('%y yr, %m mo and %d days');
```

This returns `0 yr, 0 mo and 8 days`. I want to return only `8 days`.

Or if `1 yr, 0 mo and 8 days`, return `1 yr and 8 days`

Comment: Well then you either have to check upfront what’s 0 and what’s not, and supply the according format string dynamically ... or remove all “0 abc” afterwards.

Comment: You'll just have to build the string yourself with conditionals if the `diffForHumans()` function isn't good enough for you

Comment: @Jeff,  diffForHumans() returns 8 days ago, if you tell me how i can remove this ago (

Comment: `str_replace($time->diffForHumans(), ' ago')`

Comment: @Jeff `$createdTime = Carbon::now()->parse($specialist->created_at)->diffForHumans();` if created_at is 2016-12-06, this retun 11 months

Comment: yes, it rounds.  if it were 1  year 1 month ago it might just say 1 year ago.  That is what I meant by "if it isn't good enough for you", it's not as precise as you wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `diff()` returns a `DateInterval` instance you could run conditional checks to get your expected result.

```
$createdTime = Carbon::parse($specialist->created_at)
                        ->diff(Carbon::now());

$final_string = '';
$year = '';
$month = '';
$days = '';

if ($createdTime->y) {
    $year = $createdTime->y . ' yr';
}

if ($createdTime->m) {
    $month = ' '. $createdTime->m . ' mo';
}

if ($createdTime->d) {
    $days = ' ' . $createdTime->d . ' days';
}

$final_string = trim($year . $month . $days);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a better solution rather than using `diffForHumans()` and remove `ago` with `str_replace($time->diffForHumans(), ' ago')`.

I recommand using the [CarbonInterval](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-interval) like this :

```
$now = Carbon::now();
$years = $specialist->created_at->diffInYears($now);
$months = $specialist->created_at->diffInDays($now->subYears($years));
$days = $specialist->created_at->diffInDays($now->subMonths($years));

// $hours = $specialist->created_at->diffInHours($now->subDays($days));
// $minutes = $specialist->created_at->diffInMinutes($with_duration->subHours($hours));
// $seconds = $specialist->created_at->diffInSeconds($with_duration->subMinutes($minutes));  

return CarbonInterval::years($years)->months($months)->days($days)->forHumans();

//return CarbonInterval::years($years)->months($months)->days($days)->hours($hours)->minutes($minutes)->seconds($seconds)->forHumans();
```