# Carbon diffForHumans with months

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I try to get the difference between 2 dates, between date now() and a given date in Laravel app with Carbon. I do the following in my blade

```
\Carbon\Carbon::parse(Auth::user()->properties->first()->von)->diffForHumans()
```

but this returns only the years, so taking the following example where given date is `1st September, 2011` I get as result 6 years ago The expected would be 6 years and 3 months.
 Is it possible the achive this with Carbon?

Comment: You can use [CarbonInterval](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-interval) as discribed in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47658027/4881811) !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`diff()`](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) and it's properties:

```
$diff = auth()->user()->properties->first()->von->diff(now());
```

And then display it:

```
The difference is {{ $diff->y }} years and {{ $diff->m }} months
```

Alternatively, you could get a difference in months and use it:

```
$diffInMonths = auth()->user()->properties->first()->von->diffInMonths(now());
```

Comment: 1 year 6 months 1 day ago

Comment: 1 decade 1 year 6 months ago

Comment: 4 months 3 weeks 2 days from now

Comment: I'm still looking for something like above for diff